# Web Service C# Null Exception Error in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: web-services

My Web Service URL Link : http://www.ignyte.com/webservices/ignyte.whatsshowing.webservice/moviefunctions.asmx

I am using the GetUpComingMovies operation.

*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using test.showMovies;
using test.lyrics;
namespace test
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        MovieInformation mi = new MovieInformation();
        //LyricWiki lw = new LyricWiki();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int month = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
            int year = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
            UpcomingMovie[] ucome = mi.GetUpcomingMovies(month, year);
            Label1.Text = ucome.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

*

This is what i code inside VS2010 but it keep gives me a null exception error.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 



Line 25:             int year = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
Line 26:             UpcomingMovie[] ucome = mi.GetUpcomingMovies(month, year);
Line 27:             Label1.Text = ucome.ToString();
Line 28:       
Line 29:         }
```

I need to get the names of the movies by entering month and year in the gui but it either gives me no results or null error.

How do i get the data for the upcoming movies operation?
Thanks!

Comment: Well presumably either `Label1` or `ucome` is null. We can't easily tell - I suggest you add diagnostics or use a debugger. (Calling `ToString` on an array isn't going to give you a useful output anyway though.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried doing this `Label1.Text = ucome[0].MovieName;` it also gives me the same error

Comment: Well yes, if `Label1` or `ucome` is null, then that's definitely still going to give a `NullReferenceException`. The *first* thing you need to do is work out which of those is null and why.

Comment: @JonSkeet I debugged already is `ucome` null. And the month and year is captured. But i just cant get the data out and i dont know why..

Comment: Well that sounds like you need to check what's going across the wire to/from the web service, to start with.